# My application starts and closes automatically

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

When I am running my basic Android Application with a `TextView` it is showing my text, But if I am running that code with `ImageView`, my app doesn't get open also

eg:

MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.sef.hero;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   // private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=4000;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      //  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        //    @Override
      //      public void run() {
       //         Intent homeIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
       //         startActivity(homeIntent);
        //        finish();
        //    }
       // },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sef.hero.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Hello world"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I am Running this code it is running and closing my app on Emulator. It is not showing any image it gets closed and it is not opening my application even a second also:

MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.sef.hero;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   // private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=4000;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      //  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        //    @Override
      //      public void run() {
       //         Intent homeIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
       //         startActivity(homeIntent);
        //        finish();
        //    }
       // },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sef.hero.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What's your **logcat** error?

Comment: it is not showing any error ?

Comment: What's your image format and resolution? It's something related to image

Comment: I am  not able to saw any image , if i am trying to put any image view , after running only imageview code in android studio it just open application on emulator and close down that .
And in same code i change imageview to textview with all changes , i am getting the apk file.

Comment: Did you check your `android:src="@drawable/my_image"`image that you have set here?. Just put default app icon image i.e ic_launcher and check.

Comment: Not error it shows this --> "instant run performed a full build and install since"

Comment: I am taking image of 1280*720 pixel

Comment: @RakeshKumar while changing to default ic_launcher it is doing same things opening and closing application.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of exception in Logcat?

Comment: How to check exception in logcat ?

Comment: @TNZF, When your application getting closed then you must be getting something in your Logcat any kind of error, crash or an exception, check that.

Comment: @RakeshKumar "10-06 20:53:02.608 910-910/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060054 (t=5 e=84) (error -75)"

Comment: @RakeshKumar 10-06 20:53:02.497 910-910/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

Comment: @TNZF, How about on real device?? Is it working on real device?

Comment: @RakeshKumar  yes i am running on my mobile.

Comment: Turn off the Instant Run and then after clean and rebuild the project again then run the application.

Comment: 10-06 22:30:06.566 20762-20762/com.sef.hero W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
1

Comment: 10-06 22:30:06.683 20762-20762/com.sef.hero W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060054 (t=5 e=84) (error -75)
10-06 22:30:06.684 20762-20762/com.sef.hero W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060054 (t=5 e=84) (error -75)

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:545)

Comment: @RakeshKumar i am getting upper error

Comment: You've error of vector drawable.. try my solution below

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using vector drawable for your `ImageView`,

if **yes** then consider using `AppCompatImageView` instead and use property **`app:srcCompat="[your image drawable here]"`** instead of regular `src` tag.